# Почему chrome не сглаживает градиент?

Tags: css, google-chrome, градиент

Если при создание градиента указывать угол в 30 градусов, то в chrome появляются лесенки. В firefox вся сглаживается хорошо. Если угол 45 градусов, то также в chrome отображается нормально. Можно ли это как то исправить ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPexJr

```css
#triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
#triangle:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #d3bba3 0%, #d3bba3 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #d3bba3 0%, #d3bba3 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}
#triangle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #dae5e7 0%, #dae5e7 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-240deg, #dae5e7 0%, #dae5e7 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Дело не в градиенте, дело в наклоне (deg). Возможно будет ровнее, если градиент рисовать прямой, а вращение делать через 3D, а не 2D трансформацию. Но это не точно.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что границы цветов (или прозрачности) чётко совпадают. При этом, нет места для сглаженного перехода, и какой-либо интерполяции. При указании стыков, оставляйте небольшой запас (под каждый случай, подбирается экспериментально). Например, в вашем коде, было достаточно развести границы друг от друга всего на 0.5 пикселя(!):

```css
#triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
#triangle:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #d3bba3 0%, #d3bba3 50%, transparent 50.5%, transparent 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #d3bba3 0%, #d3bba3 50%, transparent 50.5%, transparent 100%);
}
#triangle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #dae5e7 0%, #dae5e7 50%, transparent 50.5%, transparent 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-240deg, #dae5e7 0%, #dae5e7 50%, transparent 50.5%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: глубоко копаешь :) И тему и по дате - прошло 3 с половиной года

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Постоянно старые вопросы ищу - уже время прошло, появились новые технологии, появились ответы и решения того, что раньше через "костыли" и хаки делалось. Вопросы висят, а в инете одни перепосты основных параметров, и никаких тебе нюансов. Вот и актуализирую))

Comment: да я разве чё, я ничё :))) Так поздоровался просто