# Диагональный градиент из 2 частей

Tags: css, css3, градиент

При использовании

```
linear-gradient(to top right, silver 50%, blue 50%)
```

переход получается лесенкой, что особенно хорошо заметно при некоторых соотношениях сторон:

[image: скринш]

Как сделать красивый плавный переход?

```css
main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, silver 50%, blue 50%);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Про это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926053/265406

Comment: @UModeL, ой. Не видео тот вопрос, а то бы там написал...

Comment: под вопросом видно, что я тоже его специально тогда искал) Время от времени прохожу по древним вопросам без ответов...

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант - добавить 1px на переход - тогда граница получится немного размытая и будет выглядеть лучше:

```css
main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, silver calc(50% - .5px), blue calc(50% + .5px));
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Но в таком случае при увеличении масштаба переход может оказаться совсем размытым, например, вот при 500%:

[image: от лесенки]

Чтобы этого избежать можно использовать экранный пиксель:

```css
                                                  :root { --spx: 1px;           }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .09 )   { :root { --spx: 10px;          } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .25 )   { :root { --spx: 4px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .33 )   { :root { --spx: 3px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .5  )   { :root { --spx: 2px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .66 )   { :root { --spx: 1.5px;         } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .75 )   { :root { --spx: 1.333333333px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .79 )   { :root { --spx: 1.25px;        } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .89 )   { :root { --spx: 1.111111111px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1   )   { :root { --spx: 1px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1 )   { :root { --spx: 0.009090909px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25)   { :root { --spx: 0.008px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.006666667px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.75)   { :root { --spx: 0.005714285px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2   )   { :root { --spx: 0.005px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2 )   { :root { --spx: 0.004545455px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.004px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3   )   { :root { --spx: 0.003333333px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.002857143px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4   )   { :root { --spx: 0.0025px;      } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5   )   { :root { --spx: 0.002px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 6   )   { :root { --spx: 0.001666667px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 8   )   { :root { --spx: 0.00125px;     } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 10  )   { :root { --spx: 0.001px;       } }

main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to top right,
    silver calc(50% - var(--spx) / 2),
    blue calc(50% + var(--spx) / 2)
  );
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Ну и при необходимости можно добавить полный комплект фоллбэков на случай если не поддерживается calc и на случай если не поддерживаются переменные:

```css
                                                  :root { --spx: 1px;           }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .09 )   { :root { --spx: 10px;          } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .25 )   { :root { --spx: 4px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .33 )   { :root { --spx: 3px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .5  )   { :root { --spx: 2px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .66 )   { :root { --spx: 1.5px;         } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .75 )   { :root { --spx: 1.333333333px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .79 )   { :root { --spx: 1.25px;        } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .89 )   { :root { --spx: 1.111111111px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1   )   { :root { --spx: 1px;           } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1 )   { :root { --spx: 0.009090909px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25)   { :root { --spx: 0.008px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.006666667px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.75)   { :root { --spx: 0.005714285px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2   )   { :root { --spx: 0.005px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2 )   { :root { --spx: 0.004545455px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.004px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3   )   { :root { --spx: 0.003333333px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.5 )   { :root { --spx: 0.002857143px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4   )   { :root { --spx: 0.0025px;      } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5   )   { :root { --spx: 0.002px;       } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 6   )   { :root { --spx: 0.001666667px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 8   )   { :root { --spx: 0.00125px;     } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 10  )   { :root { --spx: 0.001px;       } }

main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, silver 50%, blue 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, silver calc(50% - .5px), blue calc(50% + .5px));
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, silver calc(50% - var(--spx) / 2), blue calc(50% + var(--spx) / 2));
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Вы сделали мой день))) ПлАчу...

Comment: @UModeL, чего такого?

Comment: просто представил, что эту простыню для каждого перехода на странице дописывать нужно. А ведь кто-то не разобравшись скопипастит и навставляет))

Comment: @UModeL, зачем для каждого? Переменная прописана 1 раз для всего приложения, а дальше используем и радуемся.